# What happen with the pointer members of a class if I declare a pointer?

Tags: c++, class, pointers, declaration

I have written the following code:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class Node {
public:
    int id;
    Node* n;
};

int main()
{
    Node* node;
    cout << node->n;
    return 0;
}
```

In this case I declared a pointer (it's uninitializated) but in the output I obtain an address given by "n". if I don't initializate the pointer, why does the code show me a reference?.

Comment: `node` is dangled pointer, dereference on it is UB, means anything is possible. That's all.

Comment: Loosely, only global and function- or class-`static` pointer variables are automatically initialised to 0.  C++ doesn't waste time / code initialising things - in the general case it's too hard to be sure the programmer's not doing it later anyway.  (Function static means the variable survives across invocations; class static means there's a single instance of the variable regardless of the number of object instances of the class instantiated)

Comment: `node` is an *indeterminate* variable; not dangling. It would be "dangling" if it at one time referred to some valid instance or sequence, and later said-instance or sequence was released (manner makes no difference) and the pointer was all that remained . Short answer: You have an indeterminate pointer, and dereferencing it, or even *evaluating* it (such as `if (node != NULL)` ) invokes *undefined behavior*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a wild pointer. VC compilers assign to those pointers the value `0xcdcdcdcd` which may point to the last memory in the `RAM` ( not sure of that) . You should not dereference this kind of pointers because the compiler will throw a violation memory access.If you doesn't want to assign a object of type `Node` to the pointer it is strongly recommended that you assign the pointer with `NULL` value.In this case you will always be able to check in the code if the pointer points to a real object or is not assigned by checking his address.

Comment: Unitialized memory is only filled with `0xcd` in debug builds, to quickly find bugs. In the same way deleted memory is filled with `0xdd`, and other magic numbers are used for fences.